# from pyspark.sql.types import Row and from pyspark.sql import Row

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, row, apache-spark-sql

what is differences of "from [pyspark.sql.types](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html) import Row" and "from [pyspark.sql](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql.html) import Row"?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. If you see `__init__.py` file of `pyspark.sql` module you can find it imports `Row` among the other classes.